# What's the measure of the segment $AC$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:   A line tangent at $B$ to the circle circumscribed to the triangle $ABC$, is parallel the interior bisector $CD$($D$ in $AB$).
Calculate $AC$, if $AD = 5$ and $BD=4$ (Answer:$7,5$)

My progresss:
I believe the figure is this

Th. Angle Bissector:$\triangle ABC$

$\frac{AC}{5} =\frac{BC}{4}\implies AC = \frac{5BC}{4}\\
CD^2 = AC.BC - 5.4 \implies \\
AC  =\frac{CD^2 +20}{BC}\\
\frac{5BC^2}{4}=CD^2 + 20 \implies CD = \frac{\sqrt{5BC^2-80}}{2}$

missing a relationship with BC...???

[image]

Comment: Please note $AC  =\frac{CD^2 + 20}{BC} \implies \frac {4 AC^2}{5} = CD^2 + 20$. Now given $CD = 5$, finish your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$BC$ subtends $2 \angle A$ at the center of the circlec, say $O$.

Then $\angle OBC = 90^\circ - \angle A$ and hence the tangent makes angle $\angle A$ with segment $BC$ but given the tangent is also parallel to the angle bisector, we conclude $\angle A = \angle C / 2$.

That leads to $\triangle ADC$ being isosceles and hence $~ CD = 5$.

Now plug this into your work to find $AC$.